# In Heroku, is there a way to add multiple HTTP post hooks?

Tags: heroku

I am currently using Heroku's HTTP post hook add-on to send a message to my company's chat client, but now I want to do more with it. Is it possible to add multiple HTTP post hooks, so more than one service could be notified when a deploy happens? (no I don't want to receive emails).

Thanks!
-Doug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not right now - a workaround would be having a tiny app to receives your HTTP post hook and trigger all the HTTP hooks you need.

Answer (score 6):

My friend Jared made an app for this: https://github.com/deadlyicon/deploy-hook-forker